# Convert MFRC522 UID Hex Bytes to Printable Decimal

Tags: c++, c, arduino, hex, rfid

I'm using the [MFRC522 library](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid) on my Arduino UNO to read Mifare RFID tag Info.

```
// Print HEX UID
Serial.print("Card UID:");
for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {
    Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
    Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
} 
Serial.println();
```

I've got a byte array(4) which contains the HEX UID:

```
54 C7 FD 5A
```

But I've failed to convert it to Decimal:

```
HEX(5AFDC754) => DEC(1526581076)
```

I've tried to convert the byte array to char reversely, but the compiler didn't let me print Dec.

```
char str[8];
int k = 0;

for (int i = 3; i >= 0 ; i -= 1) {
    char hex[4];
    snprintf(s, 4, "%x", mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i]);

    for( int t = 0; t < 4; t++ ) {
        if( (int)hex[t] != 0 )
            str[t+k] = hex[t];
    }

    k+=2;
}

Serial.println( str, DEC);
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You will need to combine the 4 hex bytes into a single unsigned integer.

This depends on Endianess (search for it).

For Big Endian:

```
  unsigned int hex_num;
  hex_num =  uidByte[0] << 24;
  hex_num += uidByte[1] << 16;
  hex_num += uidByte[2] <<  8;
  hex_num += uidByte[3];
```

For Little Endian, reverse the order of uidByte positions.

Comment: `unsigned int` can't store `uidByte[0] << 24`, but `long long` can't be printed with `Serial.println()`

Comment: What is `sizeof(int)` on your system?

Comment: Thanks, this works for me! `unsigned int` is four bytes, so it works perfectly.

Comment: `warning: left shift count >= width of type` I get this warning when using 'verify'. It compiles and runs fine though. Any tips?