# How to convert RC522 UID Hex Bytes to Decimal?

Tags: c++, c, node.js, raspberry-pi, rfid

I use RC522 with NodeJS and node package `mfrc522-rpi` on Raspberry pi 3+
When I trying read UID, got array of hex: 
`[E9, E5, 98, 94]`

But this UID differend from my RFID reader. I got 
`15258857`

I tryed join hex and convert to decimal, but result still different: 
`0xE9E59894.toString(10) === "3924138132"`

How can I convert UID to decimal correctly?

Comment: This doesn't look like C or C++; why is it tagged with both?

Comment: solutions on C++ or C is suitable too

Comment: @ScottHunter I tryed this solution, but it not works too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678099/convert-mfrc522-uid-hex-bytes-to-printable-decimal

Comment: What kind of RFID Card and RFID Reader are you using?

Comment: @SergioFerrerSánchez for PC this -- http://www.stronglink-rfid.com/en/rfid-readers/sl500.html

Comment: For turnstile is Vegan